# Porting wxPython to SWT/JFace

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, nebula, opal

I use some nice controls/widgets in a simple wxPython app I developed taking inspiration from the sample demo. Call it my prototype.

I am now ready to migrate my prototype to Java/SWT.

Some controls are just not there.. or.. at least.. I could not find them.

Is there anything else in the FOSS world of SWT apart from the usual:

- SWT/JFace
- Nebula
- Opal

For a while I did not know about Nebula nor Opal at all. Now I do. At least you know I have done some legwork before coming here. Could it be that I am still oblivious to some fundamental set of extensions to the core SWT?

What I am doing right now is building a table, on the left - controls I use from wxPython, on the right - equivalent controls I'll use in Java/SWT.

The right column still has some gaping blanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshots in wxWidgets I didn't saw anything, that is in SWT missing. If you share the gaps, we might be able to help you to find the right tool for you. There are many frameworks that contribute specific UI, that might be used. For example [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/),[BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) or [Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the screenshots do not really show the depth and breadth of the available samples in the demo. One has to download the actual executable, I guess. Maybe it's a type of work that I should do, that of collecting screenshots of all the demo panes presented by the wxPython demo app.. I did not know of the frameworks you mentioned and kindly linked. That's another avenue to pursue. Can you think of any others off the top of your head?

Comment: If you tell what you need, then probably I will know what to show you. There are really many frameworks that provide some UI Contribution (see http://projects.eclipse.org/list-of-projects) or there are many hacks that customize the RCP like http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/03/31/replacing-the-perspective-switcher-in-rcp-apps/.SWT is not like the most web frameworks having a ton of widgets. But also there is always the need to build something custom.

Comment: Ok, I might do just that.. I appreciate the offer to help! It'll be time consuming though as I am not a whiz at "batch screenshot taking.." and I'll have to find a place for the pics..

Comment: if you think the question is answered, please mark it as answered ;)

Comment: For now, as I am a bit daunted by the prospect of doing all those screengrabs, I suppose it is.. Thanks a lot for your kind support, I really appreciated it. Probably if I gave you more info, you'd give me more links.. ;)

Comment: The question is still open, so if you have more specific questions I'll be glad to answer them if I can of course